# Sort pandas DataFrame ignoring certain values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

there is this pandas DataFrame with values close to 1 and close to 0:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'colA': (0.97, 0.88, 0.03, 0.02),
'colB': (0.01, 0.03, 0.87, 0.99),
})
```

Sorting it according to values gives (sorting for`colB` has obviously no effect):

```
df.sort_values(['colA','colB'], ascending=False)
>>    colA  colB
>> 0  0.97  0.01
>> 1  0.88  0.03
>> 2  0.03  0.87
>> 3  0.02  0.99
```

However, I would like to sort based on only the larger values, say `> 0.5`. This would ignore the smaller values for `colA` and switch to `colB` for further sorting.

The sorted DataFrame would look like this (`row 2` and `3` are switched):

```
df.some_function(['colA','colB'], ascending=False, condition=i>0.5)
>>    colA  colB
>> 0  0.97  0.01
>> 1  0.88  0.03
>> 2  0.02  0.99
>> 3  0.03  0.87
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is replace not matched values to missing values and then sorting, last change order by new index:

```
idx = (df[['colA','colB']].where(df[['colA','colB']] > 0.5)
           .sort_values(['colA','colB'], ascending=False).index)

df1 = df.loc[idx]
print (df1)
   colA  colB
0  0.97  0.01
1  0.88  0.03
3  0.02  0.99
2  0.03  0.87
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df[['colA','colB']].where(df[['colA','colB']] > 0.5))
   colA  colB
0  0.97   NaN
1  0.88   NaN
2   NaN  0.87
3   NaN  0.99


print (df[['colA','colB']].where(df[['colA','colB']] > 0.5)
                          .sort_values(['colA','colB'], ascending=False))
   colA  colB
0  0.97   NaN
1  0.88   NaN
3   NaN  0.99
2   NaN  0.87
```

Comment: This is easily scalable to large dataframes, thank you! Very concise solution. I learned about `where` now.
I did `idx = df.where(df > 0.5).sort_values(list(df.columns), ascending=False).index` and then `df = df.loc[idx, :]` to apply it to arbitrarily large dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Build a new column which is the same as 'a', but ignores smaller values, and sort using this new value and 'b':

```
df.assign(simplified_a = np.where(df.colA<0.5, 0, df.colA))\
  .sort_values(["simplified_a", "colB"], ascending=False).drop("simplified_a", axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   colA  colB
0  0.97  0.01
1  0.88  0.03
3  0.02  0.99
2  0.03  0.87
```

Answer (score 0):

filter the datafarme based on condition, then sort, then append

```
df1 = df.where(df['colA'] > 0.5).sort_values('colA')
df2 = df.where(df['colA'] <= 0.5).sort_values('colB')

final_frame = df1.append(df2).dropna()

   colA  colB
0  0.87  0.01
1  0.88  0.03
2  0.03  0.87
3  0.02  0.99
```